# Determinant of the matrix — recursive function

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, determinants

I wrote a program which returns a determinant of a matrix. I have a problem, actually; it always returns the "0" value. I notice that my determinant always stays as 0 even though I add numbers to it.
I wrote an English translation in the comments to understand my program better. I use a method in which we select one number and then crossed the element from the column and line of the selected number and then calculate the determinant of the uncrossed elements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float wznmacierz(float*macierz, int rozmiar)/*"macierz" means a matrix and "rozmiar" is a size of matrix */
{
    if (rozmiar == 1)
        return *macierz;
    float *podmacierz = malloc((rozmiar-1)*(rozmiar-1)*sizeof(float)); // making a second matrix for uncrossed elements.    
int  wyznacznik = 0; // wyznacznik is the determinant of matrix
    for(int element_S = 0; element_S <rozmiar; element_S++) //element s is a number from first line 
    {   
        for (int w = 1 ; w < rozmiar; w++  ) //line of checking element
        {    
            for(int kolumna = 0; kolumna < rozmiar; kolumna++)//column of chcecking element
            {   
                if(kolumna == element_S)
                    continue;
                *podmacierz = macierz[(rozmiar*w)+(kolumna)];
                podmacierz++;
            }
        }
        wyznacznik += macierz[element_S]*( element_S % 2 ? -1: 1)* wznmacierz(podmacierz, rozmiar-1);
    }
    return wyznacznik;
}       


void main()
{
    float a[2][2]={{1,3},{9,8}};
    printf("%d", wznmacierz(a,2));
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to use English variable names.

Comment: made a english variables names in coma

Comment: It's worrying to see the calculation being done using `float` and not `double`.  Generally, you should use `double`.

Comment: The `printf` in `main` expects an `int` but the function returns a `float`.

Comment: I think you should be printing out the matrices that you generate to ensure that they're the correct sub-matrices of the input.  I think you could sensibly create a special case for a 2x2 matrix.  I see memory allocation via `malloc()`, but I see no memory being freed.  This is a memory leak. If you special-case 2x2, you'll need a bigger test matrix than your existing 2x2 matrix (at least once you've demonstrated that the calculation for a 2x2 matrix is correct).

Comment: I believe `wyznacznik` should be a `float` (while you're using `float`).

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings.  The first argument of `wznmacierz` has type `float *`, but you're passing it a `float (*)[2]`.  Your compiler should have complained about that.

Answer (score 2):

Change `void main` to `int main`, because `main` returns an `int`.

In `printf("%d", wznmacierz(a,2));` , change `%d` to `%g`, because `%d` is for formatting an `int`, but `wznmacierz` returns a `float`. `%g` will format a `float`. Also add `\n` after `%g` to complete the line being output.

In `printf("%d", wznmacierz(a,2));`, change `a` to `*a` because `wzmacierz` expects a pointer to a `float`, not a pointer to an array of `float`. This is a kludge to get your program “working” quickly; see Notes below.

You cannot use `podmacierz` both to hold the start address of the allocated array and to increment to places within the array. Inside the loop on `element_S`, put `float *p = podmacierz;` to make a second pointer, and change the uses of `podmacierz` inside that loop to `p`.

Before returning from the function, use `free(podmacierz);` to release the allocated space.

### Notes

In `main`, `a` is declared as `float a[2][2]`. This makes it an array of 2 arrays of 2 `float`. In the call `wznmacierz(a,2)`, `a` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. That produces a pointer to an array of 2 `float`. However, `wznmacierz` is declared with a parameter `float*macierz`, which is a pointer to a `float`.

One way to fix this is to pass `*a`. Once `a` is converted to a pointer to its first element, a pointer to an array of `float`, then applying `*` produces the thing that pointer points to, an array of `float`. Then that array of `float` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, producing a pointer to a `float`. You could also write `wznmacierz(&a[0][0], 2)`.

This produces a pointer of the correct type for `wznmacierz`, which then access the array by calculating element locations, using `macierz[(rozmiar*w)+(kolumna)]`. This nominally calculates correct addresses for the array elements, since arrays are laid out in memory contiguously, but it is bad style unless necessary, and some people might consider it not to conform to the C standard in a pedantic sense.

One fix would be to define `a` in `main` as `float a[2*2] = {1, 3, 9, 8};`. Then the matrix is implemented as single flat array of `float` everywhere it is used.

Another fix would be to upgrade `wznmarcierz` to use two-dimensional arrays. A number of changes are needed to do this. I have not tested them, but I think they are at least:

- Change `wznmacierz(a,2)` to `wznmacierz(2, a)`.
- Change the declaration of `wznmacierz` to `float wznmacierz(int rozmiar, float macierz[rozmiar][rozmiar])`.
- Change the use of `macierz` inside the function from `macierz[(rozmiar*w)+(kolumna)]` to `macierz[w][kolumna]`.
- Change `float *podmacierz = malloc((rozmiar-1)*(rozmiar-1)*sizeof(float));` to `float (*podmacierz)[rozmiar-1] = malloc((rozmiar-1) * sizeof *podmacierz);`.
- Remove the `float *p = podmaciarz;` that I told you to insert above.
- Inside the loop using `w`, insert `float *p = podmacierz[w];`.
- Change `macierz[element_S]` to `macierz[0][element_S]`.
- Change `wznmacierz(podmacierz, rozmiar-1)` to `wznmacierz(rozmiar-1, podmacierz)`.